# What is the best way to install database from script files for .Net developers?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, version-control, development-environment, database-schema

We have a project and have some DB script files which create the database, tables and stored procedures. We are using C# .net and everyone is using Visual Studio 2010. Is there a tool out there that integrates into Visual Studio or a build tool similar to ant (I think Nant looks a bit immature) that will aid developers in doing a check out of the code and installing the database easily.

At the moment I am think of some .bat files in the db directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use [cgywin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run a script to concatenate the sql scripts and then run this on the db (you just have to make sure the sql scripts are ran in the correct order).

It allows you to maintain separate files for each table, which is particularly useful if your using SVN etc and don't like correcting conflicts.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make sure the create script are saved using the ANSI encoding and not unicode etc.

master_script="create_all.sql"
#path="C:\\"

#cd $path

cat script1.sql\
    script2.sql\
    somefolder/script1.sql\
    >$master_script

notepad $master_script

#rm $master_script
```